# Browsersync and/or Gulp Keeps Resetting CSS

Tags: css, gulp, bootstrap-4, browser-sync

I have Gulp and Browsersync setup. However, whenever I run npm start, the CSS in the Style.css file resets. The index.html changes remain and I have no trouble pushing the initial CSS changes to github. Does anyone know why these CSS additions are being re-set and if there is anything I can do to stop it from happening?

https://github.com/jwolfe890/bootProj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is set up to use `scss`. This gets compiled to normal `css`.
If you write your code directly into the `css` file, the gulp job will just recompile the `scss` and overwrite your changes.
To make this less likely to happen, a convention is to not have the output of your gulp job write into the same directory you use for developing (src).

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss','src/scss/*.scss'])
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css")) <-- put this somewhere else
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});
```

To fix your issues, just write your style in the `scss` file.